# Why this function in imagepicker program js doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have problem with this function, I use this http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/ and I want to create option for user to forward to proper website after choosing appropriate image. Forwarding is working but images dissappears with this code. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<script src="js.js"></script>



<!-- scripts for imagepicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="image-picker.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="image-picker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="image-picker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";
        //wait for the page to be fully loaded
        window.onload = function() {
            initialize();
        }
    </script>



</head>
<body>


<!--code for imagepicker-->
<select multiple="multiple" class="image-picker show-html" id="selectImg">
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" value="http://cats.com">Cute Kitten 1</option>
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" value="http://dogs.com">Cute Kitten 2</option>
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" value="http://dogsandcats.com">Cute Kitten 3</option>

</select>

<button href="#" id="forwardButton">Forward</button>

<script>

function initialize() {

    var choice = document.getElementById("selectImg").value;

    //changes destination when you set or change your choice
    document.getElementById("selectImg").onchange = function() {
        choice = document.getElementById("selectImg").value;
    }

    //when button is clicked
    document.getElementById("forwardButton").onclick = function() {
        if (choice !== ("" || "undefined")) {
            window.location = choice;
        }       
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you haven't initialized image picker.

from http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

> Then just call imagepicker on the target elements.
>   $("select").imagepicker()

Why do you load image-picker.js and the same file in minified version?

Comment: just mistake from recent code :) WORKING. Thank you very much